PC Build showing Error Code 55 on first boot and won't open BIOS
I'm building my first PC and just got everything together. I turned on power and started it up but it didn't post. It showed code 55, which seems to be a RAM issue.
I have two DDR5 units in the A2 and B2 slots of my ASUS Z690-E motherboard. I tried to reinsert them to ensure that they had good connection, but they light up with everything else when the PC starts, so I'm having a hard time believing they are the point of issue.
I went to enter BIOS to try to fix this, but found trouble there too. I'm using a Womier keyboard which has a display LCD. Point is, it kept turning on and off when connected to every USB port I tried. No keyboard, no BIOS.
I'm a little lost here, so I would greatly appreciate some help.

is the RAM on the supported memory module list? note that just because the take power, doesn't mean they are fully compatible. https://rog.asus.com/motherboards/rog-strix/rog-strix-z690-e-gaming-wifi-model/helpdesk_qvl_memory/

I found all of the parts from PCPartPicker so I'd imagine they're compatible seeing as the site said they were. The motherboard supports DDR5 memory.

minor correction, the motherboard only guarantees support for DDR5 memory recorded on the Hardware Compatibility List linked in my first comment. other modules may or may not work. they should, but its generally best to order parts that are on the HCL.

I'll check it out, thanks

It looks like there are several that are very similar (Mine is FF3D532G6000HC30DC01, several models such as FF3D532G6600HC34DC01 are represented). A little unfortunate that I didn't catch that when ordering. Do you think that would also cause a problem with power to the usb ports?

I would not expect ram compatibility to impact power (though usb is a complicated bus) but Id start by checking all the power connections, and make sure your CPU power lines are plugged in.

DDR5 is DDR5; I have never in 30 years of building computers ever run into a situation where a memory module of the correct type (as an example DDR5) was incompatible with a system that supported DDR5. Those 2 parts would essentially be identical.

I'd like to check all options before getting new RAM sticks, I tried to move them to each DIMM port in different configurations to no avail. I also plugged in a second 8-pin CPU power cable, which didn't do much. My biggest hang-up is that I can't get into BIOS. I don't know if that's the keyboard not communicating or what, but its making troubleshooting harder for sure. I found that 55 can also activate for cpu issues, so I'll check that tomorrow.

Ok, interesting update. Last plan for the night was to take out one of the two RAM sticks. That worked for some reason. BIOS is up, keyboard is responding, new error code is 98. Its still a problem, but its a new problem. I like a new problem better than an old one.
